# Popover for an OS X status bar app on NSStatusItem (MAAttachedWindow alternatives?)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to show some message pointing to my Mac OS X application icon living only in the status bar:

[image]

I believe [**MAAttachedWindow**](http://mattgemmell.com/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass/) was a thing 7-8 years ago but I couldn't even get its demos working and it's not written for ARC.

I'm wondering if there's an open source library or some code snippet doing the same thing people use these days. Even finding the coordinates of my status bar icon is a mystery to me at this point.

I don't want to show popover when user clicks on my icon, I will just show it to give a heads up to the user that app is over there in the status bar.

Comment: If your application targeting 10.7+ you do not need any 3rd party library, you can do it same with using [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @mohacs great answer. However I found that many use cases of `NSPopover`+`NSStatusItem` are for showing menu contents as popover. I want to show popover below the icon without user clicking to the status icon. I still find that very tricky. Spent some few hours and still no luck. e.g. I can't find a `view` to provide at: `[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:]`. Apparently that should be a view that has a window, which I guess NSStatusItem doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was creating my own NSStatusItem, which you can find an example of here:

http://shaheengandhi.com/using-nspopover-with-nsstatusitem/

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using `NSPopover` if possible, but if that does not suit your needs you could always try [`RBLPopover`](https://github.com/github/Rebel/blob/master/Rebel/RBLPopover.h) or [`SFBPopovers`](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers). If you decide to go with `NSPopover`, you might want to check out [`AXStatusItemPopup`](https://github.com/aschuch/AXStatusItemPopup) which seems promising, although I have not personally tested it.

Comment: I found those but they're not quite helpful since I don't want it to be shown when clicked but rather when some event happens in the background. Please see my comment under the question above.

Comment: You cannot get access to a status item's window unless you set a custom view on your status item. If you want the behavior you're talking about, you need to set a custom view.

Comment: Yep it seems like I will go with it. Thanks.